# Implicit would allows for eliding "s" of third person conjugation?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, third-person

I'm on a pinch here:

> Then when a request comes, the server *can* compare the version number
>   present in the digest with the current version of the site, and only
>   **push** assets that have changed between the two versions.

I think that I should write "push" instead of "pushes", because of the *can* auxiliar that I used before. Am I right? What is the precise rule in this case?

Comment: If you write *push*, it's implicitly *can push*. If you write *pushes*, you can't have an implicit *can*, and I think it sounds much better to use *it only pushes*.

Comment: That sounds OK to me.  I guess if you were unsure, you could repeat the 'can' before 'push'.

Answer (score 1):

> The server can [do stuff], and only push assets [blah].

or

> The server can [do stuff], and only pushes assets [blah].

Both are fine as, in the first, "only push" implies "can only push" or "will only push".

If you want to avoid ambiguity you can add the "can" or "will" into your sentence but I had no problem reading it as it is.